# ruby basics mentor

Tags: discussion

I am looking for someone who is interested in answering specific questions, someone I can connect with while I learn Ruby basics.  I am learning on my own and I come across questions I cannot find or do not have the exact answer I need to move on.

Can I create myself a little community of willing people here that I can ask private questions?

Comment: consider using [Ruby chat room](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/5676/ruby-on-rails) at Stack Overflow. As for *private* questions, forget about it - Stack Exchange model isn't compatible with this kind "features", see eg [MSO post here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/431/any-way-to-send-a-personal-message-to-another-user)

Comment: I cannot use the chat room unless I have "20" reputation.  If I had one willing rubyist to ask a few questions, that would be amazing.  Ever learned something new and just need some confirmation.  So much easier to move on.  Learning Ruby is very high on my priorities and I am quite the detailed person and need that little extra info to pull it all together.

Comment: did you consider getting that `20` reputation to get into chat? that's four votes for your questions or two votes for your answers or 10 approved suggested edits - not too much really

Comment: I would insider that route.  I do feel like my questions are so simple and I do not have answers for people unless we talk knitting.  I will give that a try however.  Thanks.

Comment: @lorindaapps We don't have a Stack Exchange site for knitting (yet?), but did you know we have [89 Q&A sites](http://stackexchange.com/sites#traffic) on a variety of topics? If you find one that interests you, and earn 200 rep on it, you'll automatically be awarded a 100 rep bonus on all other sites (we call that the association bonus). That bonus will take care of little annoyances as not being able to access chat.

Answer (score 6):

Programmers, Stack Overflow and [Stack Exchange](http://stackexchange.com/) in general are question and answer sites, mentoring is not really part of neither the philosophy nor the format of the sites. You mention that:

> I am learning on my own and I come across questions I cannot find or do not have the exact answer I need to move on.

Well, that's great! Go ahead and ask those questions, on Programmers if they are conceptual (design, architecture, etc) or on Stack Overflow if they are technical (implementation issues, programming tools). Your [single question](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/52123/where-is-the-best-place-to-teach-myself-a-language-and-which-one) on Programmers received a fair amount of upvotes, some good answers and earned you enough reputation to use our chat (but unfortunately not the Stack Overflow chat).

I don't know why you'd want to ask private questions but I should point out that even our chat rooms are public, the only form of private communication on Stack Exchange is between moderators, or between a moderator and a regular user, when issues of private nature arise.

> I would insider that route. I do feel like my questions are so simple and I do not have answers for people unless we talk knitting. I will give that a try however. Thanks.

Who cares if your questions are simple? If you present them clearly, and show us that you've at least tried a bit to solve your problem before asking, your questions are more than welcome. If you don't feel confident enough to ask questions, you should read and follow the advice given on:

- Matt Gemmell's excellent article [What have you tried?](http://mattgemmell.com/2008/12/08/what-have-you-tried/), and
- Jon Skeet's [Writing the perfect question](http://msmvps.com/blogs/jon_skeet/archive/2010/08/29/writing-the-perfect-question.aspx) blog post, the canonical guide on asking questions on Stack Overflow.

Comment: Thank you!  I do not need/ want private messages.  I merely seek to evade annoyed experienced programmers.  I guess if my question sucks, oh well!  I shall ask something later...

Comment: Hi lorindaaps, to further support what Yannis is saying, also check this out, [you don't need to be an expert to ask expert questions](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/151369/155826). I think this applies to your situation perfectly. :)